# Liferay - export sitemap to human-readable form

Tags: liferay, sitemap

We would like to put our Liferay sitemap to VCS, so new developers can start developing more quickly. So far, I was unable to find out how to export Liferay's sitemap to some human-readable form. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by  human-readable form?
For example, a tree of pages is fine?
And where do you want to show it? In an image, in a portlet, or?

Comment: I meant something like XML or proeprties config. Something that can be version-controled. If you mean like programmatic tree of pages, that's fine. I would like to show it in portlet ... let other programmers bootstrap our Liferay app quicker.

Comment: Other solution can be extracting .lar file from portlet. It's a zip file that can be extracted. Then maybe a simple program can convert it to any format. And, it is possible to import it again. (So, technically, it is going to be 2 files, one human-readable, and one for import)

Comment: Doesn't sound too bad. It's more important for it to be VCS-able than to be human-readable. I will see what can I do with LAR.

Comment: Let me know if I won my first bounty or not :)

Comment: Sure, but I cannot give bounty to comment. If you want, place it to answer and I will decide later what's right for me (after weekend :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site Map can be retrieved in two ways. (None of them actually are designed to be human-readable but they can use)

1- XML

> Liferay Portal makes this very simple for administrators by generating the sitemap XML automatically for all public web sites.

2- LAR file (Liferay Archive)

> The Export / Import tab allows you to export the pages you create into a single file, called a LAR (Liferay Archive). You can then import this file into any server running Liferay, and all of your pages will be copied.

Using the first format, you can generate any kind of human-readable format (like trees), and attaching the second file, you can send the information, and others can upload it.

I hope it works :)

Quotes are from Liferay [documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/page-creation-and-manageme-2)

Comment: I have not fully resolved the issue yet, but I will either end up exporting and versioning LAR, or coding againts Liferay API to do it manually. Anyway, thanks for pointing me the right direction, enjoy the bounty :)

Comment: I am happy to hear that. I wish I had more time and develop some samples for this LAR file :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple method is to simply access `[myserver.com]/sitemap.xml`. Although I'm not certain it is clean enough for you. You can see it in action on Liferay's website, http://www.liferay.com/sitemap.xml.

Comment: So let's suppose I configure my Liferay with all the portlets. Then I will access myserver/sitemap.xml and save it. Can other engineers in my team somehow import it?

Comment: No, for that you'll want to see the other answer for the LAR file but it is not human readable. It will simply extract all the plugin data in what ever form it sees fit.